# How to correctly map huge json file to Java (pojo)?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Large json files are available (from 100 MB to 2 GB).

How I can create java (pojo) from json? I need to get the names of all fields. For example, one class can have more than 1000 fields.

Tried the following libraries & online services:

JsonSchema2Pojo works well, but has a limit of about 50,000 characters at a time. Due to the presence of limits, I cannot completely map the class. Need to partially copy the json each time and then remove the duplicate fields.

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

JsonToJava
https://github.com/astav/JsonToJava

Also tried several other online services. They also have limits or do not work correctly.

Example of json file:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[27.5618791,53.902334]},"properties":{"ele":"280","name":"Минск","place":"city","capital":"yes","name:ar":"مينسك","name:be":"Мінск","name:bg":"Минск","name:bo":"མིན་སིཀ།","name:cs":"Minsk","name:cu":"Мѣньскъ","name:cv":"Минск","name:de":"Minsk","name:el":"Μινσκ","name:en":"Minsk","name:eo":"Minsko","name:es":"Minsk","name:et":"Minsk","name:fa":"مینسک","name:fi":"Minsk","name:fr":"Minsk","name:ga":"Minsc","name:gl":"Minsk - Мінск","name:he":"מינסק","name:hi":"मिन्‍स्‍क","name:hr":"Minsk","name:hu":"Minszk","name:hy":"Մինսկ","name:ia":"Minsk","name:io":"Minsk","name:is":"Minsk","name:it":"Minsk","name:ja":"ミンスク","name:ka":"მინსკი","name:kk":"Минск","name:kn":"ಮಿನ್ಸ್ಕ್","name:ko":"민스크","name:ku":"Mînsk","name:kv":"Минск","name:ky":"Минск","name:la":"Minscum","name:lt":"Minskas","name:lv":"Minska","name:mk":"Минск","name:ml":"മിൻസ്ക്","name:mr":"मिन्‍स्‍क","name:nl":"Minsk","name:no":"Minsk","name:oc":"Minsk","name:os":"Минск","name:pl":"Mińsk","name:pt":"Minsk","name:ru":"Минск","name:sk":"Minsk","name:sl":"Minsk","name:sr":"Минск","name:sv":"Minsk","name:ta":"மின்ஸ்க்","name:tg":"Минск","name:th":"มินสก์","name:tt":"Минск","name:ug":"مىنىسكى","name:uk":"Мінськ","name:ur":"منسک","name:vi":"Minxcơ","name:vo":"Minsk","name:yi":"מינסק","name:zh":"明斯克","website":"https://minsk.gov.by/","int_name":"Minsk","name:ast":"Minsk","name:ckb":"مینسک","name:csb":"Mińsk","name:jbo":"misk","name:mhr":"Минск","name:myv":"Минск ош","name:nds":"Minsk","name:pnb":"منسک","name:rue":"Мінск","name:sah":"Минскай","name:szl":"Mińsk","name:udm":"Минск","name:wuu":"明斯克","nat_name":"Мінск","old_name":"Менск","wikidata":"Q2280","wikipedia":"ru:Минск","population":"1982444","admin_level":"2","alt_name:be":"Менск","alt_name:vi":"Minsk;Minxcơva","name:prefix":"город","old_name:be":"Менск","addr:country":"BY","name:bat-smg":"Minsks","name:sr-Latn":"Minsk","wikipedia:be":"Мінск","wikipedia:en":"Minsk","wikipedia:pl":"Mińsk","addr:postcode":"220000","is_in:country":"Belarus","name:be-tarask":"Менск","source:name:oc":"Lo Congrès","is_in:continent":"Europe","population:date":"2018-01-01","capital_ISO3166-1":"yes","source:population":"Белстат","is_in:country_code":"BY"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.5861178,53.9510657],[27.5861196,53.9510294],[27.5862319,53.9510313],[27.5862302,53.9510676],[27.5861178,53.9510657]]]]},"properties":{"building":"yes"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.5885075,53.9512721],[27.5885398,53.9511614],[27.5887363,53.9511813],[27.588704,53.9512919],[27.5885075,53.9512721]]]]},"properties":{"building":"yes"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.5881428,53.9512622],[27.5881704,53.9511135],[27.588421,53.9511296],[27.5883935,53.9512783],[27.5881428,53.9512622]]]]},"properties":{"building":"yes"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.5892179,53.9516538],[27.5893274,53.9516011],[27.5893778,53.9516374],[27.5894352,53.9516098],[27.5895358,53.9516823],[27.5893689,53.9517626],[27.5892179,53.9516538]]]]},"properties":{"building":"yes"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.588949,53.9517486],[27.5891273,53.9516621],[27.5892764,53.9517686],[27.5890981,53.9518551],[27.588949,53.9517486]]]]},"properties":{"building":"yes"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.5867595,53.9500825],[27.5867648,53.9499951],[27.5869291,53.9499985],[27.5869238,53.9500859],[27.5867595,53.9500825]]]]},"properties":{"building":"yes"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.5830382,53.9503042],[27.5830422,53.9502013],[27.5832783,53.9502045],[27.5832743,53.9503074],[27.5830382,53.9503042]]]]},"properties":{"building":"yes"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.5820906,53.9497446],[27.5820973,53.9496721],[27.5822371,53.9496765],[27.5822305,53.949749],[27.5820906,53.9497446]]]]},"properties":{"building":"yes"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.5477403,53.8940388],[27.5482144,53.8939744],[27.5482459,53.8940791],[27.5482929,53.8940736],[27.5483083,53.8941424],[27.5482593,53.8941471],[27.5482741,53.8942048],[27.5485718,53.8943067],[27.5487113,53.8943028],[27.5487556,53.8943755],[27.548895,53.8944261],[27.5487985,53.894513],[27.5488079,53.8945841],[27.5483385,53.8943889],[27.548317,53.8943202],[27.5481439,53.8942549],[27.5481045,53.8941843],[27.5479863,53.8942063],[27.5479953,53.8942214],[27.5478248,53.8942506],[27.5477403,53.8940388]]]]},"properties":{"name":"Инженерный корпус метрополитена","building":"yes"}}
]}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this might be helpful for you [Jackson Streaming API](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api)

Comment: You won't like the answer but: by not doing things this way. If you have that much data, have it live in a database, not in files (and whether those are json, xml, csv, it really doesn't matter), and then pull data from that database as needed in whatever language you need to work in.

Comment: Thank you for attention. I have read this article. But in this article, he himself creates the necessary fields: String parsedName = null; Integer parsedAge = null;  For a class, I can have a huge number of fields (more than 1000). I cannot create them manually.

Comment: What do you want to do once you know all the fieldnames? Any suggestion we can give you highly depends on that

Comment: "You won't like the answer but: by not doing things this way. If you have that much data, have it live in a database, not in files... "  -   The online service makes it possible to download data in different formats. (geojson, json, xml) Unfortunately, the sqlite database has size limitations and cannot be downloaded from the service. My goal is to map json to the postgres database.

Comment: "What do you want to do once you know all the fieldnames? Any suggestion we can give you highly depends on that"  -  My goal is to map json to the postgres database. To do this, I need to form a dto class.

Comment: Do you want to create new tables based on the data? Or do you have existing tables where you want to insert that data? You don't need a DTO for this. You should use DTOs whenever possible, but in a use-case like this (where you have more or less unknown input) creating a DTO is not necessary

Comment: Thank you for attention. Yes, I need create new tables based on the data. Note that all types of fields must be string.

Comment: Do I need use @ JsonAnySetter? Or are there other options for mapping variable json data?

Comment: I'd use a kind of streaming/event-based API https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api , or even simplest possible parser like https://github.com/anatolygudkov/green-jelly instead of POJO. Go through the file twice - 1st time to collect all field names and create a table, 2nd time - to write each row into DB (with batching, if this is JDBC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your advices.
Implemented in the following way:
I used JsonAnySetter annotation to set all fields instead creating pojo with all of the possible fields.
Here is my Dto's

FeatureDto

```
@Getter
@ToString
public class FeatureDto {

  @JsonProperty("type")
  private String type;
  @JsonProperty("geometry")
  private GeometryDto geometry;
  @JsonProperty("properties")
  private PropertiesDto properties;

}
```

PropertiesDto

```
@Getter
@ToString
public class PropertiesDto {

  private List<FieldDto> fieldDtos = new ArrayList<>();

  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setProperties(String code, Object value)
  {

    if(value instanceof ArrayList) {
      ArrayList<Object> list = (ArrayList<Object>) value;
      StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
      list.forEach(o -> stringBuffer.append(o).append(", "));
      fieldDtos.add(new FieldDto(code, stringBuffer.toString()));
      return;
    }

    fieldDtos.add(new FieldDto(code, value.toString()));
  }

}
```

FieldDto

```
@Data
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FieldDto {

  @JsonProperty("code")
  private String code;
  @JsonProperty("value")
  private String value;

}
```

Here is the json source:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[27.5618791,53.902334]},"properties":{"ele":"280","name":"Минск","place":"city","capital":"yes","name:ar":"مينسك","name:be":"Мінск","name:bg":"Минск","name:bo":"མིན་སིཀ།","name:cs":"Minsk","name:cu":"Мѣньскъ","name:cv":"Минск","name:de":"Minsk","name:el":"Μινσκ","name:en":"Minsk","name:eo":"Minsko","name:es":"Minsk","name:et":"Minsk","name:fa":"مینسک","name:fi":"Minsk","name:fr":"Minsk","name:ga":"Minsc","name:gl":"Minsk - Мінск","name:he":"מינסק","name:hi":"मिन्‍स्‍क","name:hr":"Minsk","name:hu":"Minszk","name:hy":"Մինսկ","name:ia":"Minsk","name:io":"Minsk","name:is":"Minsk","name:it":"Minsk","name:ja":"ミンスク","name:ka":"მინსკი","name:kk":"Минск","name:kn":"ಮಿನ್ಸ್ಕ್","name:ko":"민스크","name:ku":"Mînsk","name:kv":"Минск","name:ky":"Минск","name:la":"Minscum","name:lt":"Minskas","name:lv":"Minska","name:mk":"Минск","name:ml":"മിൻസ്ക്","name:mr":"मिन्‍स्‍क","name:nl":"Minsk","name:no":"Minsk","name:oc":"Minsk","name:os":"Минск","name:pl":"Mińsk","name:pt":"Minsk","name:ru":"Минск","name:sk":"Minsk","name:sl":"Minsk","name:sr":"Минск","name:sv":"Minsk","name:ta":"மின்ஸ்க்","name:tg":"Минск","name:th":"มินสก์","name:tt":"Минск","name:ug":"مىنىسكى","name:uk":"Мінськ","name:ur":"منسک","name:vi":"Minxcơ","name:vo":"Minsk","name:yi":"מינסק","name:zh":"明斯克","website":"https://minsk.gov.by/","int_name":"Minsk","name:ast":"Minsk","name:ckb":"مینسک","name:csb":"Mińsk","name:jbo":"misk","name:mhr":"Минск","name:myv":"Минск ош","name:nds":"Minsk","name:pnb":"منسک","name:rue":"Мінск","name:sah":"Минскай","name:szl":"Mińsk","name:udm":"Минск","name:wuu":"明斯克","nat_name":"Мінск","old_name":"Менск","wikidata":"Q2280","wikipedia":"ru:Минск","population":"1982444","admin_level":"2","alt_name:be":"Менск","alt_name:vi":"Minsk;Minxcơva","name:prefix":"город","old_name:be":"Менск","addr:country":"BY","name:bat-smg":"Minsks","name:sr-Latn":"Minsk","wikipedia:be":"Мінск","wikipedia:en":"Minsk","wikipedia:pl":"Mińsk","addr:postcode":"220000","is_in:country":"Belarus","name:be-tarask":"Менск","source:name:oc":"Lo Congrès","is_in:continent":"Europe","population:date":"2018-01-01","capital_ISO3166-1":"yes","source:population":"Белстат","is_in:country_code":"BY"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.5861178,53.9510657],[27.5861196,53.9510294],[27.5862319,53.9510313],[27.5862302,53.9510676],[27.5861178,53.9510657]]]]},"properties":{"building":"yes"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.5885075,53.9512721],[27.5885398,53.9511614],[27.5887363,53.9511813],[27.588704,53.9512919],[27.5885075,53.9512721]]]]},"properties":{"building":"yes"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.5881428,53.9512622],[27.5881704,53.9511135],[27.588421,53.9511296],[27.5883935,53.9512783],[27.5881428,53.9512622]]]]},"properties":{"building":"yes"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.5892179,53.9516538],[27.5893274,53.9516011],[27.5893778,53.9516374],[27.5894352,53.9516098],[27.5895358,53.9516823],[27.5893689,53.9517626],[27.5892179,53.9516538]]]]},"properties":{"building":"yes"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.588949,53.9517486],[27.5891273,53.9516621],[27.5892764,53.9517686],[27.5890981,53.9518551],[27.588949,53.9517486]]]]},"properties":{"building":"yes"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.5867595,53.9500825],[27.5867648,53.9499951],[27.5869291,53.9499985],[27.5869238,53.9500859],[27.5867595,53.9500825]]]]},"properties":{"building":"yes"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.5830382,53.9503042],[27.5830422,53.9502013],[27.5832783,53.9502045],[27.5832743,53.9503074],[27.5830382,53.9503042]]]]},"properties":{"building":"yes"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.5820906,53.9497446],[27.5820973,53.9496721],[27.5822371,53.9496765],[27.5822305,53.949749],[27.5820906,53.9497446]]]]},"properties":{"building":"yes"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[27.5477403,53.8940388],[27.5482144,53.8939744],[27.5482459,53.8940791],[27.5482929,53.8940736],[27.5483083,53.8941424],[27.5482593,53.8941471],[27.5482741,53.8942048],[27.5485718,53.8943067],[27.5487113,53.8943028],[27.5487556,53.8943755],[27.548895,53.8944261],[27.5487985,53.894513],[27.5488079,53.8945841],[27.5483385,53.8943889],[27.548317,53.8943202],[27.5481439,53.8942549],[27.5481045,53.8941843],[27.5479863,53.8942063],[27.5479953,53.8942214],[27.5478248,53.8942506],[27.5477403,53.8940388]]]]},"properties":{"name":"Инженерный корпус метрополитена","building":"yes"}}
]}
```